# Update Windows 10 Enterprise PC to 1511 per DVD

Tags: windows-10, updates, windows-10-v1511

For any reason one of my Windows 10 Enterprise PC don't offer the update 1511.

I suppose that the update failed.

I can download the new ISO Image from my MSDN account. Is this the correct way to install the update via DVD to download this image and start the update from this DVD ISO image?

PS (after the question was answered): I have the problem with more than 1 PC. I have installed the MSDN Windows 10 Enterprise version. Currently I detected 3 Laptops/PCs that don't offered the update. All Windows 10 Home machines got this update.

Comment: There isn't a wrong way to install the update.

Comment: But what happens if I start the Setup on the 1511 ISO on a Win10 version? So if there would be a "wrong way", the setup will not start...

Comment: You will install the update?

Comment: Yes. I want to force this machine (of a developer) to execute this new build. I don't know why only this machine isn't updated up to know...

Comment: Mount the appropriate Enterprise version of the 1511 Windows 10 .iSO and run the setup.  The installation will be updated.  There isn't a "wrong" way to install this update.

Comment: It worked! Just done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

I had exactly the same issue, and eventually (Dec 1st) gave up waiting.

Mounted the ISO, ran the setup, and ensured that `Keep Files and Settings` was selected when given the option.

As soon as the install completed and I'd rebooted, Windows Update straightaway started offering me updates again, including the Windows Defender ones which I'd been getting every day anyway, but more to the point, the cumulative updates were also coming through.

My Win 10 install was clean on to bare metal on 29th September (so a lot more than 30 days ago), I didn't have Defer Updates selected, and I hadn't installed the update and then uninstalled it again (in fact, I don't think that's possible with 1511).

But yes, update-installing from the MSDN 1511 ISO seems to work fine, and unblocks the flow of normal Windows updates.

Comment: I still have a laptop  that is still waiting for the update. Also Win 10 Enterprise

Comment: Me too. Still waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. Searching over internet I have found this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574263(v=vs.85).aspx

> When the development of a new Windows 10 feature upgrade is complete, it is initially offered to Current Branch computers; **those computers configured for Current Branch for Business will receive the feature upgrade (with additional fixes) at a later date, generally at least four months later.** An additional deferral of at least eight months is available to organizations that use tools to control the update process. During this time, monthly security updates will continue to be made available to machines not yet upgraded.

It looks like we can either wait at least four months or install from ISO.

Comment: That article suggests that 'Defer upgrades' needs to be selected for the PC to be configured as 'Current Branch for Business' - mine was not, so I don't see how that applies.

Comment: It gives some clue why Current Branch for Business does not see updates yet. It should be visible after at least for months so in February. 
I also had not "Defer upgrades" selected, so re article I should be on "Current Branch" and see updates. But I didn't. So I think is either a bug in that windows version or this should be configured somewhere else. But I give up waiting and installed update from ISO.