# My Windows 10 Enterprise still has not got the November update (1511)

Tags: windows-10-v1511

I'm running the Enterprise version of Windows 10 on one of my computers at home, and Windows 10 Pro on another one.  The Pro computer got the November update 1511 several days ago, but the Enterprise one still has not received it.  Even when I check for updates manually through settings I am told that the computer is up-to-date.  But Settings > System > About tells a different story:

[image: Windows 10 Enterprise]

I don't see the `1511` that I see in my other computer.  Moreover, the [updates FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-update-faq) says that after the November update I should no longer be able to see the older updates in the update history.  But on this computer I can indeed see the older update history.

Do I have to download the ISO and install the update manually?  Or is Microsoft putting people in queues for the purpose of delivering the update?

**ADDENDUM**

Since this thread has been getting a few views of late, I thought I should summarise my situation, and subsequent decisions, clearly.

I first encountered the problem when the 1511 update was released.  Even after a prolonged period of waiting, my installation of Enterprise did not get the update.  The only solution available to me was to download the ISO from MSDN.

I encountered the problem once again when the 1607 update was released.  I waited for about two weeks, and even tried changing numerous settings in `gpedit.msc`, but nothing worked.  So eventually I erased my disk and installed Windows 10 Pro instead.

I believe `seagull's` experience is unique.

Comment: This is a known intentional non-issue.  The update is being rolled out to everyone.  If you just wait eventually you will get it.  If you can't wait, then download the Version 1511 `.ISO` from [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx), mount the .ISO, and run the installer.  `winver` will actually report the version of Windows 10 you are running.  This is a exact duplicate of [Update Windows 10 Enterprise PC to 1511 per DVD](http://superuser.com/questions/1002667/update-windows-10-enterprise-pc-to-1511-per-dvd)

Comment: Patience.  I just got the update today.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.  Moderators, please feel free to close the question.

Comment: My original comment was 100% when I said it, it's still correct, numerous people have confirmed that fact when I have them similar statements about the VLC and enterprise versions of Windows 10 and version 1511 and version 1607.  Only weeks after, version 1607 was released, was the upgrade assistant tool updated to support enterprise versions

Comment: @Shredderroy Update 1607 might take until November 2016 to be pushed, wiping your system is a solution, but like I said a year ago it's not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I no longer believe this answer to be correct! (August 2016)**

I believe Enterprise editions do not get the 1511 update because of their type - Enterprise is the version you roll out to Employees of a company; you don't want them upgrading their Windows version (and potentially losing compatibility) without your explicit say-so as the administrator.

If you download the 1511 ISO from MSDN and mount it or burn it to a USB stick, you'll be able to run it from the Desktop and install it without losing any files.
This, I think, is the only way for Enterprise users to get the update.

Comment: Although this is the "correct" answer, personally I don't believe it to be the case any longer. I did eventually get the 1511 update, and I got 1607 a few hours after it was released, despite my Enterprise status. Apologies if this misled anyone.

Comment: That is very good to know.  I still have not received the 1607 update for my Enterprise edition, but as soon as I do, I will post the news here.  Did you have to change any settings in 1511 in order to get the automatic update for your copy of Enterprise?

Comment: No, it came out a few hours after release on the same day via Windows Update. I hope you get yours soon - if not, you can always install over the OS if you can source an ISO.

Comment: For what it is worth, I still don't have the offer.  I have even tried tweaking the settings in `gpedit.msc` and waiting for a week, but nothing has worked.  I think I am just going to install Windows 10 Pro this weekend.

Comment: @Shredderroy the Windows free upgrade ended on July 29, if that's what your talking about,  in every case of an update to Windows 10 the ISO was released the same day.  Waiting months for the update makes no sense, version 1607 might no pushed to all users, until November 2016