# How to install Windows 10 Anniversary Update on Windows 10 Enterprise edition

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

I have a laptop with Windows 10 Enterprise edition installed (64bit).

I haven't got the Windows 10 Anniversary Update from the normal Windows Update (I have clicked `Check for updates`). So I want to install it manually.

I have downloaded the the update from [the Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history). However when I run it, the Update Assistant says

[image: Windows 10 will not run on this PC Operating System: Contact your system administrator to upgrade Windows Server or Enterprise editions]

But I'm my own system administrator. I've installed Enterprise Edition from MSDN Subscriber downloads.

How do I update to the Anniversary Edition?

Comment: Maybe there is no anniversary update for enterprise editions?

Comment: For Enterprise Editions, you may need to do an in-place upgrade by downloading the ISO. Similar issue for Nov update with Enterprise Editions. http://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-10-enterprise-install-november-update/

Comment: Get the 1607 Enterprise ISO from MSDN, mount the ISO, run setup.exe and select upgrade (keep everything)

Comment: You get it from the same place you got your original Enterprise edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Windows 10 Enterprise still has not got the November update (1511)](http://superuser.com/questions/1002899/my-windows-10-enterprise-still-has-not-got-the-november-update-1511)

Comment: @magicandre1981 when I run `setup.exe` I don't get any "upgrade (keep everything)" option. Clicking `next` lots of times eventually gets me to a `Ready to install` which just offers me to `Install Windows 10 Enterprise` and `Keep personal files and apps`. Sounds like a reinstallation rather than an upgrade, making me loose configured apps etc.

Comment: keep everything = "Keep personal files and apps"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To Upgrade the Windows 10 Enterprise Editions, get the 1607 ISO from MSDN/Volume Licensing portal, mount the ISO via double click on it, run the setup.exe on the virtual DVD drive, now select Upgrade

[image]

and next select `Keep personal files and apps`

[image]

This upgrades Windows 10 to the Version 1607 and keeps all installed Windows Applications.

Comment: I guess this is probably correct. Unfortunately, after I upgraded Boot Camp, the ISO led me to a full reinstall, all settings and apps lost. Lesson: don't upgrade Boot Camp

Comment: Did the upgrade itself work, and was the Boot Camp upgrade separate?

Comment: @LucasMcGraw First I started to do the Anniversary update, and it looked pretty much like this answer. Then I cancelled it (since it sounded like it would loose my sewtting). Then I upgraded Boot Camp separately (from 4 to 6). Then I no longer got the updgrade option above when trying to install the Anniversarhy update.

Comment: this solution seems to be working for me but it would be nice to know why you have to do this and it doesn't work automatically through windows update (why the "contact your admin message")

Comment: @coding4fun because it is a Volume License version and no retail / OEM

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution that actually works for Windows 10 Enterprise. Takes some tweaking and it will install Build 1607. Make sure you have a backup. Secondly make sure you are signed in with your Microsoft Account. Then follow these steps below.

1. Open regedit.exe and navigate to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
2. Change ProductName to Windows 10 Professional
3. Change EditionID to Professional
4. Navigate now to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Wind­ows NT\CurrentVersion
5. Change ProductName to Windows 10 Professional
6. Change EditionID to Professional
7. Close regedit.exe (no need to restart)
8. Start the Windows 10 Pro installation from your installation media. (Download the Media Creation tool from Microsoft - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209 or https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and click on the Download Tool now)
9. Do the upgrade, will download and install, keep all files & settings.
10. Will reboot several times, once finished, log back in with your Microsoft Account and it will automatically link your enterprise key to the install and you will be back on Enterprise Edition and have Build 1607 installed.

I did it on 4 machines today and it worked every time.

Comment: are you serious? I wouldn't recommend that way.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!! Even the Microsoft Support couldn't fix this problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( The upgrade didn't have the initial error, but one screen in it said that an error occurred and wouldn't continue.

Comment: Not able to find productName under currentversion following 1st step itself. Where exactly its located?

Comment: I could not get the tool to work but it got farther on each attempt. Eventually it failed with an error code that google suggested was related to downloading updates while attempting to install. Sure enough, the anniversary update downloaded in the background and installed succesfully.

Comment: I've got `0xa0000400` in the installer when trying to use this method for upgrading to Creators update.

Answer (score 4):

Simply turn off "Defer Upgrades" option from the advance settings of Window Updates.
Window Key> Settings> Update and security> Advanced option. then off the Defer upgrade. And again search for Windows Updates. You will get one.

Comment: I did not have "Defer Upgrades" set.

Comment: Confirmed! It works as of now, I had it turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I 've struggling for a month. Today i got inspired and finally found the solution. My pc has windows 10 Enterprise installed which is domain joined.
So when i am on Windows Update screen the Check box **Check online for updates form Microsoft Update** is unchecked. Check the box, update and during update recheck it.

[image]

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The updates you show in your answer do not include he Anniversary Update

Comment: I know my intension was not to show the updates. But the check box. I have already installed it. I cannot rollback just to take a screenshot.