# Still not recieving Windows 10 Anniversary Edition update (build 14393)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I use Windows 10 Enterprise and the Windows 10 Anniversary Edition update still doesn't appear in Windows Update

Is anyone else having this problem?

How can I get the Anniversary Edition update for Windows 10 Enterprise Edition?

Comment: @MátéJuhász That's incorrect. For example take this [Windows.com blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/08/02/how-to-get-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/): "The Windows 10 Anniversary Update is being rolled out to Windows 10 PCs across the world in phases starting with the newer machines first."

Comment: You might want to hold off installing Anniversary Update for a couple of months until some of the bugs are ironed out.

Comment: Enterprise versions of Windows 10 are not update to major versions releases like Version 1607 through Windows Uodate.  Download the .ISO from the same location your originally downloaded previous Enterprise ISO your used.  There are questions with answers from with me with the specific website if you don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Enterprise Edition. Talk to your sysadmin about it.

Enterprise does NOT install big updates automatically.

You can read more about it here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/08/02/whats-new-for-it-pros-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/

There is already another question regarding this "issue".

[How to install Windows 10 Anniversary Update on Windows 10 Enterprise edition](https://superuser.com/questions/1110580/how-to-install-windows-10-anniversary-update-on-windows-10-enterprise-edition)

Comment: I would have up voted this answer if it contained a link to the VLK website and specific instructions

Comment: I added a link, and fixed a typo.