# Windows 10 Enterprise Cannot Apply Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise with all of the latest updates, except for the Anniversary Update. I just received it the other day for my system, but I cannot install it. Here is what I get:

1. Update is available
   [image: Anniversary Update Available]
2. Preparing to install finishes
3. Downloading finishes
4. Preparing to install gets to about 91%
   [image: Preparing to Install Updates]
5. It fails with this message
   [image: Installation Fails]

*Notes:*

- I've already looked at [this posting](https://superuser.com/questions/1110580/how-to-install-windows-10-anniversary-update-on-windows-10-enterprise-edition), which is not related
- There is a message in the Windows Event Viewer, but per [this site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6d4baee8-80e6-4f52-902e-7a598a7d5533/error-0x80070714?forum=w8itproinstall), disabling SQL Server services didn't do the trick:

> Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x8024200D: Feature update to Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1607.

Here is some information on my system. Does anything look awry? I am on a domain with no known policy preventing this update.
[image: System Information]

Comment: So what have you tried already exactly?  Rebooting?  Resetting Windows Update? SFC scan? CHKDSK?  Are you getting your updates directly from MS, or do you use WSUS at your company?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sufficient space on your System Drive? Is your system time correct? (I know sounds stupid)...also when it does install make sure you have about an hour for it to complete...I had it take about that long on 2 different machines

Answer (score 0):

This is a common failure, and Microsoft's suggestions never seem to work for anyone.  However, trying a few times can sometimes eventually get it to work.  Also, disabling anti-virus before doing the update has had a few successes as well.

I would suggest downloading the Media Creation Tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10)

Use the tool to create a bootable USB or DVD.  Once it's finished, boot from the media you create and install away.  Be aware that this update can sometimes take ages.  Mine took 5 hours on an i7-6700 with 16GB of RAM and an SSD.

If for some reason the tool I linked above also fails, then you are likely experiencing issues with the download, which makes it network-related.  In this case, try downloading it and creating your boot media on another system, on another network.