# no "Windows subsystem for Linux (Beta)" available

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1511, developer-tools

I'm trying to use Linux shell on my windows and this is my system info:

[image]

I followed this instruction: [Install Linux bash on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)
but there is no "Windows subsystem for Linux (Beta)" available.

can anyone help for solving this issue?

Answer (score 3):

> I followed this instruction: Install Linux bash on windows but there is no "Windows subsystem for Linux (Beta)" available.

You don't have an eligible build of Windows 10 installed.  You have 1511 installed but you need to have 1607 or 1703 installed.

> Can anyone help for solving this issue?

The solution to your problem is simple, install/update, so you have 1607 or 1703 installed.  You can also just wait until 1709 is released.

Taken directly from the article you provided:

> Windows 10’s Anniversary Update offers a big new feature for developers: A full, Ubuntu-based Bash shell that can run Linux software directly on Windows. This is made possible by the new “Windows Subsystem for Linux” Microsoft is adding to Windows 10

Anniversary Update is 1607 you currently have the November Update installed which by the way will stop receiving security updates shortly

[How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I should point out that Windows 10 Enterprise handles feature updates slightly different.  You have to download the ISO for the same location you originally downloaded your ISO which was used to install it.  You will be unable to update to 1607 through Windows Update.  How this is accomplished is well documented in other questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1110580/how-to-install-windows-10-anniversary-update-on-windows-10-enterprise-edition) at Superuser.  If you no longer have access to the source downgrade to Professional.