# Update Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB and keep activation status

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-activation

My situation is almost identical to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1110580/how-to-install-windows-10-anniversary-update-on-windows-10-enterprise-edition). I have just bought a used laptop that has Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB v1507, Build 10240. Windows is activated, but i don't know the product key. I want to get the latest update on it (Spring Udate 1803) and using the answer to beforementioned question i downloaded iso of Win10 1803 to do inplace installation, but i can't find any info regarding activation status. Will i keep the Windows activation when i install Enterprise 1803 from iso or will it ask for product key (which i don't have)? I've googled that after Threshold 2 update activation info is stored in Microsoft database and you no longer need to provide a key when reinstalling, but Threshold 2 was 1511 update and my version is 1507 and LTSB has no updates available.

So how do i upgrade my Enterprise LTSB to something new and keep my Windows license intact?

Comment: Enterprise versions of Windows are not sold outside of Volume Licensing situation.  Your not going to buy a single license as a single user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2016, you would need access to, the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) which would mean you have a license to LTSB 2016.  Otherwise you need Windows Software Assurance which gives you the right to upgrade LTSB 2015 to LTSB 2016.

You can perform an in-place upgrade just like Windows 10 Professional, Home, and Enterprise and Education support.  Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2015 cannot be upgraded to Windows 10 Enterprise Version (1703,1709, or 1803).

> So how do i upgrade my Enterprise LTSB to something new and keep my Windows license intact?

If you only have a license to Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2015 this cannot be done.

> Will i keep the Windows activation when i install Enterprise 1803 from iso or will it ask for product key (which i don't have)?

Your Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2015 license key wouldn’t be able to activate a Windows 10 Enterprise installation.  You would also need access to the KMS server to activate your installation anyway.  You could in theory perform the upgrade then chnage the VLK product key to an applicable Windows 10 Enterprise key.

> I've googled that after Threshold 2 update activation info is stored in Microsoft database and you no longer need to provide a key when reinstalling, but Threshold 2 was 1511 update and my version is 1507 and LTSB has no updates available.

This change was only applicable to Windows 10 Professional and Windows 10 Home.

> My situation is almost identical to this question. I have just bought a used laptop that has Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB v1507, Build 10240.

Your situation is extremely different.